# @RequestBody issue binding field named "email" jackson-databind v-2.8.4 and spring-boot-starter-parent v-1.4.2.RELEASE

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am trying to bind json with `@RequestBody`

controller method **signature**

`public String update(@RequestBody MyDto myDto)`

**my dto**

```
public class MyDto {
    String staff;
    String user;
    String email;
    // constructor, getter, setter go here
}
```

**json string**

```
{
    "staff":"its staffname",
    "user": "its username",
    "email": "myemail"
}
```

**Problem**

staff and user string are populated on server side but `email field is null`

**`when i change the name to something other than email the problem goes away`**

Comment: It seems like the server side is not expecting a string. Can you check it, please?

Comment: @AlbertVilaCanela ya it does expect String on server! I think you didn't read my whole question

Comment: Is your setter name correct - `setEmail` and not `setEMail` or something like that? Are there any Filters that could modify the request before it reaches the Controller?